# bottom tabbar disappears and leave black when pushed from UITableViewController to UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitabbar

In my use case, I want to hide the bottom tabbar when navigating away from UITabbarController.

I was using

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: tableData[indexPath.row]["vcIdentifier"]!)
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.show(vc!, sender: self)
```

It sorta works, because the pushed view controller doesn't have tabbar at bottom. However, as soon as I click on navigate, the bottom tabbar of the "sender" view controller vanishes and leaves black area.

Please let me know if you need to have more information about anything. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pushed view controller doesn't have a tab bar at the bottom, you can add this lifecycle of view controller codes.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Hi Ozdil thanks for the answer. I found that using .hidesBottomBarWhenPushed on the destination View Controller does the trick too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use segue if you want to hide tabbar while going to the next screen. it will automatically hide it.

Comment: Later I realized that the behaviour was caused by a line of code that wasn't meant to be there.
I was setting destination view controller's tabbar.isHidden by accident.